# Как я могу учесть holidays в коде для правильного количества рабочих дней в SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Я рассчитываю кол-во рабочих дней с помощью запроса в SQL:

```
SELECT
  day :: DATE,
  extract('dow' FROM day) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AS working_day
FROM generate_series('2015-01-01', (date_trunc('day', pday() + INTERVAL '1 month') :: DATE - 1)
, INTERVAL '1 day') AS day
```

Результат запроса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу учесть holidays в этом запросе? У меня есть отдельная таблица Holidays, которая выглядит следующим образом: country, date, type. 
И мне необходимо учесть только по определенным странам Federal Holidays (Это указано в колонке type).

Comment: Добавить в запрос таблицу Holidays как ещё один источник данных, с требуемым отбором (по стране), и учитывать связанные (LEFT JOIN, кстати) из неё данные при расчёте поля working_day

Comment: По какому полю джойнить?

Comment: По дате, ясен пень, плюс предотбор по типу и, если надо, то по стране.